# Querying objects added to a non committed session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy

So I placed this question without too much context, and got downvoted, let's try again...

For one, I don't follow the logic behind SQLAlchemy's `session.add`. I understand that it queues the object for insertion, and I understand that `session.query` looks in the connected database rather than in the session, but is it at all possible, within SQLAlchemy, to query the session without first doing `session.flush`?  My expectation from something which reads `session.query` is that it queries the session...

I am now manually looking in `session.new` after a `None` comes out of `session.query().first()`.

---

There's two reasons why I don't want to do `session.flush` before my `session.query`,

- one based on efficiency fears (why should I write to the database, and query the database if I am still within a session which the user may want to rollback?);
- two is because I've adopted a [fairly large program](http://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop), and it manages to define its own `Session` whose instances causes flush to also commit.

So really the core of this question is who's helping me find an error in a GPL program on github!

This is a code snippet with a surprising behaviour in bauble/ghini:

```
# setting up things in ghini
# <replace-later>
import bauble
import bauble.db as db
db.open('sqlite:///:memory:', verify=False)
from bauble.prefs import prefs
import bauble.pluginmgr as pluginmgr
prefs.init()
prefs.testing = True
pluginmgr.load()
db.create(True)
Session = bauble.db.Session
from bauble.plugins.garden import Location
# </replace-later>

# now just plain straightforward usage
session = Session()

session.query(Location).delete()
session.commit()
u0 = session.query(Location).filter_by(code=u'mario').first()
print u0

u1 = Location(code=u'mario')
session.add(u1)
session.flush()

u2 = session.query(Location).filter_by(code=u'mario').one()
print u1, u2, u1==u2

session.rollback()
u3 = session.query(Location).filter_by(code=u'mario').first()
print u3
```

the output here is:

```
None
mario mario True
mario
```

here you have what I think is just standard simple code to set up a database:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Unicode

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    code = Column(Unicode(64), index=True, primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self, code=None):
        self.code = code
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.code

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///joindemo.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
```

with this, the output of the same above code snippet is less surprising:

```
None
mario mario True
None
```

Comment: You have disabled [autoflush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing), so your `mario, none, False` works as expected. A query is fired *against the DB*, and if you don't either manually or automatically flush your changes held in the session to the DB, the query cannot see those changes. And flush does not imply commit, so something else is up, and you should provide a [mcve] about that, or otherwise make it more clear what you mean by "rolling back wont work".

Comment: I have disabled autoflush because I'm trying to, as you also mention, produce a Minimal example, starting from [a program I adopted](http://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/), where unit tests rely on autoflush being disabled.

Comment: »flush does not imply commit, so something else is up«, and I am trying to look that up in the ghini.desktop code and I don't recognize it. and that code is far from Minimal.

Comment: »A query is fired against the DB« — since `query` is a method to the session, I assumed I was querying the session, so it's surprising to me that `session.query` does not return objects in `session.new`.

Comment: if anybody wants to help me look [deeper in the code](https://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/blob/ghini-1.0-dev/bauble/db.py)? thank you.

Comment: well, the code I gave is enough, but only given the Session as built by bauble/ghini. I understand the need to make the example 'minimal', but once I have found the minimal code causing the trouble, I have already solved the trouble. I am now not flushing and querying new objects using this small workaround I wrote. but I agree it would be interesting finding out how bauble/ghini manages to produce such a strange situation.

Comment: btw: if you think this is has become an intriguing question, then maybe you want to remove your downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why flushes in bauble end up emitting a COMMIT is the [line 133 in `db.py`](https://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/blob/36485b092d261610a92274a88fead6191d35ea81/bauble/db.py#L133) where they handle their history table:

```
table.insert(dict(table_name=mapper.local_table.name,
                  table_id=instance.id, values=str(row),
                  operation=operation, user=user,
                  timestamp=datetime.datetime.today())).execute()
```

Instead of issuing the additional SQL in the event handler using the passed in transactional connection, **as they should**, they execute the statement itself as is, which means it ends up using the engine as the bind (found through the table's metadata). Executing using the engine has [autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) behaviour. Since [bauble always uses](https://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/blob/36485b092d261610a92274a88fead6191d35ea81/bauble/db.py#L283) a [`SingletonThreadPool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.SingletonThreadPool), there's just one connection per thread, and so that statement ends up committing the flushed changes as well. I wonder if this bug is the reason why bauble disables [autoflush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.autoflush)...

The fix is to change the event handling to use the transactional connection:

```
class HistoryExtension(orm.MapperExtension):
    """
    HistoryExtension is a
    :class:`~sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension` that is added
    to all clases that inherit from bauble.db.Base so that all
    inserts, updates, and deletes made to the mapped objects are
    recorded in the `history` table.
    """
    def _add(self, operation, mapper, connection, instance):
        """
        Add a new entry to the history table.
        """
        ...  # a ton of code here
        table = History.__table__
        stmt = table.insert(dict(table_name=mapper.local_table.name,
                                 table_id=instance.id, values=str(row),
                                 operation=operation, user=user,
                                 timestamp=datetime.datetime.today()))
        connection.execute(stmt)

    def after_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        self._add('update', mapper, connection, instance)

    def after_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        self._add('insert', mapper, connection, instance)

    def after_delete(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        self._add('delete', mapper, connection, instance)
```

It's worth a note that [`MapperExtension`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/deprecated.html#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension) has been deprecated since version 0.7.

---

Regarding your views about the session I quote ["Session Basics"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html), which you really should read through:

> In the most general sense, the `Session` establishes all conversations with the database and represents a “holding zone” for all the objects which you’ve loaded or associated with it during its lifespan. It provides the entrypoint to acquire a **`Query` object, which sends queries to the database** using the `Session` object’s current database connection, ...

and ["Is the Session a cache?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache):

> Yeee…no. It’s somewhat used as a cache, in that it implements the identity map pattern, and stores objects keyed to their primary key. However, it doesn’t do any kind of query caching. This means, if you say `session.query(Foo).filter_by(name='bar')`, even if `Foo(name='bar')` is right there, in the identity map, **the session has no idea about that. It has to issue SQL to the database**, get the rows back, and then when it sees the primary key in the row, then it can look in the local identity map and see that the object is already there. It’s only when you say `query.get({some primary key})` that the `Session` doesn’t have to issue a query.

So:

> My expectation from something which reads session.query is that it queries the session...

Your expectations are wrong. The `Session` handles talking to the DB – among [other things](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

> There's two reasons why I don't want to do session.flush before my session.query,
>
> - one based on efficiency fears (why should I write to the database, and query the database if I am still within a session which the user may want to rollback?);

Because your DB may do validation, have triggers, and generate values for some columns – primary keys, timestamps, and the like. The data you thought you're inserting may end up something else in the DB and the `Session` has absolutely no way to know about that.

Also, why should SQLAlchemy implement a sort of an in-memory DB in itself, with its own query engine, and all the problems that come with synchronizing 2 databases? How would SQLAlchemy support all the different operations and functions of different DBs you query against? Your simple equality predicate example just scratches the surface.

When you rollback, you roll back the DB's transaction (along with the session's unflushed changes).

> - two is because I've adopted a fairly large program, and it manages to define its own Session whose instances causes flush to also commit.

Caused by the event handling bug.

Comment: wow ... I'm in the middle of something else, and this is not something I can read in 2 minutes, so I'll postpone. thank you very much until then.

Comment: (I'm adding contribution to the sources. and I'm adding your name among the copyright holders. if you want, I can add your email address in the copyright line).