# Would dirty attributes affect a session.query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I create an sqlalchemy session and change some properties of some model, would these changes apply when making a `query` prior to any `flush` or `commit` on the session?

I could not find any proper documentation addressing this state.

Specifically I came across this when trying to validate DB invariants in a model created/updated event listener. I know I have the dirty models in `session.dirty`, would I need to query them manually in addition to any standard `session.query()` I make?

Comment: I think this is strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240437/querying-objects-added-to-a-non-committed-session-in-sqlalchemy, except for the Bauble specific parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to "Would dirty attributes affect a `session.query`" is *no*, as stated in ["Is the Session a cache?"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache):

> However, it doesn’t do any kind of query caching. This means, if you say `session.query(Foo).filter_by(name='bar')`, even if `Foo(name='bar')` is right there, in the identity map, the session has no idea about that. It has to issue SQL to the database, get the rows back, and then when it sees the primary key in the row, *then* it can look in the local identity map and see that the object is already there.

In practice it is not so simple, since in its default configuration SQLAlchemy periodically flushes changes held in the `Session` to the database. This is known as [autoflush](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.autoflush) and it ensures that queries emitted to the database observe the state as it is held in the `Session`.

In ["What does the Session do ?"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do) it is also stated that

> It provides the entrypoint to acquire a `Query` object, which **sends queries to the database** using the `Session` object’s current database connection,

So if you have disabled autoflush, or are in a context where a flush cannot happen, you will have to manually handle dirty objects.